# How to have my program list every item off of a list randomly and only once

Tags: python, list, random

I'm trying to have a function that uses the random import to randomly select a value from the list [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], print that value, then repeat itself until all the numbers are selected. The problem I'm having is then making sure when it repeats itself it won't choose that number again. What I've tried is:

```
def ListArranger():
    randomPick = random.choices(list)
    if len(list) > 0:
        if list[randomPick] != " ":
            print(list[randomPick])
            list[randomPick] = " "
            ListArranger()
        else:
            ListArranger()
```

I run into the problem that says list indices must be integers or slices, not list. I'm assuming it's having a problem because I'm trying to set the list value to a string, but I can't figure out how to work around this

Comment: Use `return lst.pop(random.choice(len(lst)))` which return random item from given collection and delete it from this collection.

Comment: See [How much research?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).  Return to the `random` documentation and look for `shuffle`.

Answer (score 4):

The obvious choice that nobody seems to mention is [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample):

```
def ListArranger(lst):
    return random.sample(lst, len(lst))

for pick in ListArranger(range(9)):
    print(pick)

4
0
8
1
2
3
7
6
5
```

Comment: That's probably the best solution, pretty straightforward.Good to learn something new.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution:

```
import random

def ListArranger(list):
    if len(list) > 0:
        randomPick = random.choice(list)
        print(randomPick)
        list.remove(randomPick)
        ListArranger(list)

list = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
ListArranger(list)
```

Output:

```
2
8
7
1
3
4
0
5
6
```

This function takes a list as an argument an calls itself until the list is empty.

It removes a random element of the list in each recursive call while printing out the removed element.

Answer (score 1):

The error comes from line lines **`3,4,5`**

Because you are indexing your list with a list in all those lines.
**randomPick** is a list not an integer or a slice that's what the error indicates.

**Example:**
`print(randomPick[ **[1,2,3,4]** ]` here is the actual problem.

You can only index a list by an **integer** or a **slice**.

**Solution:**

```
import random

lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
check_lst = []

while True:
    random_num = random.choice(lst)
    
    if random_num in check_lst:
        continue
    elif random_num not in check_lst:
        check_lst.append(random_num)
        print(random_num)
    
    if len(lst) == len(check_lst):
        print("Finish the loop")
        break
```

Comment: I believe NF was trying to solve this problem recursively.  Your iterative solution works.  Consider improving it by changing while True to while len(lst) > len(check_lst).  Then you would only need the middle condition (currently elif...) and can get rid of the other two conditions. You get an up-vote.

Answer (score 1):

You can [`shuffle()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) copy (quote from [*docs*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists): *"All slice operations return a new list containing the requested elements."*) of given *list* once and yield from ([PEP 380](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/)) shuffled list from [generator function](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generators).

```py
from random import shuffle

def ListArranger(lst):
    lst_copy = lst[:]
    shuffle(lst_copy)

    yield from lst_copy
```

You can iterate over this function which will return you every time new random element from `lst`.

If you don't need to keep source list untouched, you can omit copying, shuffle list itself and iterate over it.

Comment: You might as well return `lst_copy`. The list is there in-memory already and provides all the functionality of the generator. And it is quite cheap for the client to turn a list into a generator, but it is expensive the other way round.

Comment: It goes without saying that using the built-in shuffle method is more efficient that brute-forcing with random.choice.  However, I assume that the problem is trying to teach a novice coder how to replicate the result of shuffle without actually using the built-in method.

Comment: @schwobaseggl, check last sentence from answer ;-) Also I've just wanted to use `yield from` statement, it's one of rare times when it could be applied. Ofc, I can just return `iter(lst_copy)` or `lst_copy` itself as you suggested.

Comment: @pakpe Then there are still well known linear ways to do that.

Answer (score 1):

```
import random
lst=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
lstlen=len(lst)
def ListArranger():
    if len(lst)!=0:
        randomPick=random.choice(lst)
        print(randomPick)
        lst.pop(lst.index(randomPick))
        ListArranger()
    else:
        for i in range(lstlen):
            lst.append(" ")
            
ListArranger()
```

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)).

Answer (score 0):

If you think of your list as a **stack**, you can just `shuffle()` once and then `pop()` each element off in-sequence until you are done.

Also, this is a chance to use a generator.  You can turn any function into a generator simply by adding a `yield <something>`.  Then you can use it in a `for` statement.

Our input list remains intact because we internally `copy()` it.

```
from random import shuffle

def chooseOneWithoutReplace(items):
    data = items.copy()
    shuffle(data)
    while data:
        yield data.pop()
    # nothing more to yield
    # generator ends -> outer for loop ends

daysOfWeek = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
for i in chooseOneWithoutReplace(daysOfWeek):
    print(i)
```

Output

```
1
4
5
3
7
2
6
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `shuffle`, which does just that with a given sequence.

```
def listArranger(a):
    random.shuffle(a)
    for item in a:
        print(item)
```

Do *not* shadow a built-in name with a local variable: `list` is perhaps the most common **bad** variable name.

Pass your list into the function, rather than making it an assumption of the outer scope.